# Oracle SQL Loader - How to do field count check and reject records?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

### Oracle Table Structure.

```
create table EmployeeTemp  
(  
  Name   VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,  
  Age NUMBER(3),  
  Gender VARCHAR2(10)        
);
```

### SQL Loader Control File

```
LOAD DATA  
REPLACE   
INTO TABLE EmployeeTemp  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS  
(  
  Name   CHAR(80),  
  Age    INTEGER EXTERNAL,  
  Gender CHAR(10)  
)
```

### Data File:

```
John Williams|23|Male    
Caser|78|    
Brit    
Sam|34||extrafield
```

How to reject a record which has has more fields or fewer fields in data file compared to the number of fields in Database table?

In the data file example:

1. Record 'Sam' need to be rejected as it has 4th field (Extra field ).
2. Record 'Brit' need to be rejected as it has not passed null or empty value for Gender field. ( Having fewer field information)
3. 'John Williams' & 'Caser' record has either data or null/empty values for all 3 fields is provided. So they should not be rejected.

Please suggest how to achieve my requirement and what changes needed in the Oracle SQL loader Control file (As I don't have option to change table structure to make Age and Gender field as not null)?

Comment: Just looking at this data without loading it, the 'John Williams' record seems like it would load OK. Anyway, I think if you changed the AGE and GENDER fields in EmployeeTemp to NOT NULL it would satisfy your need.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to acheive this without changing the table structure in oracle?   (As i don't have option to change table structure in reality. I should have put this constraint in the question earlier, anyway just updated. Sorry.)

Comment: Could you run a `sed` command on the data to filter out the "bad" records and redirect the "good" records to a new file? Something like this: `cat test.dat | sed -n -r -e '/^([A-Za-z ]*)[|]([0-9]{1,3})[|]([Mm][Aa][Ll][Ee]|[Fe][Ee][Mm][Aa][Ll][Ee])$/p' > test2.dat`